# C# Draw multiple Lines

Tags: c#, line, draw

I'm drawing multiple lines by using this code, but I feel there is a better way of doing this.
E.g. by using a multidimensional array? or a list?

```
    private void drawLines()
    {
        int[] x1 = {   0,   0, 112, 222,   0, 333,   0,   1};
        int[] x2 = { 334, 334, 112, 222, 334, 333, 334,   1 };
        int[] y1 = { 100, 200, 300, 300,   1, 300, 300, 300 };
        int[] y2 = { 100, 200,   0,   0,   1,   0, 300,   0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < x1.Length; i++)
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            Grid myGrid = gg;
            line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            line.X1 = x1[i];
            line.X2 = x2[i];
            line.Y1 = y1[i];
            line.Y2 = y2[i];
            line.StrokeThickness = 2;
            myGrid.Children.Add(line);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What about strcucts and/or classes? And a method that returns line.

Comment: Seems to me like this is a `Polygon`, not a line...

Comment: If this is `Polygon`, check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: What are you targetting? WPF, ASP, Winforms, something else entirely??  - In GDI+ you collect Points in an Point[] array, or better a List<Point> and send them into the Graphics.DrawLines method, together with a Pen..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make a Line class having start and end point of the line in struct Point and make list of that class instead of having four arrays.

```
public class MyLine
{
     public Point StartPoint {get; set;}
     public Point EndPoint {get; set;}

     public void DrawLine()
     {
         //Draw line code goes here
     }
}
```

Now you have line class with required field and method to draw line. You drawLines method that might be in some other class will create list of MyLine class and can draw that list of Lines using Line class method `DrawLine`

```
private void DrawLines()
{
    List<MyLine> listMyLines = new  List<MyLine>();
    listMyLines.Add(new MyLine{StartPoint = new Point(0, 100), EndPoint = new Point(334, 100)});       

    for (int i = 0; i < listMyLines.Count; i++)
    {
         listMyLines[i].DrawLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be better.

```
private void drawLInes()
{
    drawLines(
        new int[] { 0, 334, 100, 100 },
        new int[] { 0, 334, 200, 200 },
        new int[] { 112, 112, 300, 0 }
        // ...
        );
}

private void drawLines(params int[][] lines)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        Line line = new Line();
        Grid myGrid = gg;
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line.X1 = lines[i][0];
        line.X2 = lines[i][1];
        line.Y1 = lines[i][2];
        line.Y2 = lines[i][3];
        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        myGrid.Children.Add(line);
    }

}
```